# App crashes on certain actions when using instruments, how to find reason?

Tags: iphone, crash, instruments

I have an App with a Navigation Controller, several sub Controllers.

- With XCode Debug I can't find any errors.
- With iPhone running unplugged, I can't find any errors.
- With Instruments running the App on Simulator it doesn't crash.
- With Instruments running the App on iPhone it crashes when I click forth and back between certain ViewControllers. It's not happening everytime, but very often.

My boss also reported that on his iPod it crashes sometimes, so I'm quite confused now. How should I proceed ? (still quite new to instruments). How can I find out what makes the app crash ?
Is there a way to launch instruments next to debugger ? Crash Logs don't tell me much, or maybe I don't know how to read them correctly.

Comment: Did you try Build and Analyze??

Comment: Guess what, I'm using XCode for almost a year and I didn't know about this handy tool...
I watched the developer videos of the new XCode 4 and thought, they have so cool stuff there, I need this new XCode not realizing that I have at least some handy stuff in 3.2.3 already :D
Thanks. And I think I might have found the problem with your help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My experience with instruments is decidedly mixed.  Sometimes there are crashes that I can't explain.  And some of these crashes don't happen when I am not using instruments.  That said, instruments can also provide useful information, and your situation may be one of those times.

Based on your description, it is possible that you have memory leaks.  So I would suggest running it on the simulator with instruments to look for leaks.  [In xCode, select Run>Run with performance tool>leaks, then click on the leaks panel in the instruments window that comes up.]

Comment: What I described with "With Instruments running the App on Simulator it doesn't crash." is what you are suggesting. I guess it wasn't formulated clear enough

Comment: I'm also coming across this issue in Xcode 5; app runs fine on the simulator and on device, but crashes with specific app actions when run with a leaks or allocations instruments.