# Application is crashing when running with instruments

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4, xcode-instruments

Hi Everyone , 
              My application  is running fine in iPad. but when i am running app using instruments time profiler, its getting crash .

What may be the reason?

I saw some help like

[App crashes on certain actions when using instruments, how to find reason?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168494/app-crashes-on-certain-actions-when-using-instruments-how-to-find-reason)

But didn't get much help .

Comment: In which way it crashes?

Comment: Actually , in my app first screen is login screen, after entering user name and password when i am pressing button it crashing there.

Comment: Maybe you're running in Debug-Configuration? Check your schemes. If your "Analyze" tool has "Debug" activated, it might crash when using Instruments.

Comment: Hi Jia , I am using leaks and allocation instruments . Where i can check for "Debug" setting?

Comment: In XCode, click on "Manage schemes". In the scheme you're using, you'll find the default actions (Run, Test, Analyze, Profile, Archive). In "Profile" (I wrote "Analyze" before, that's nonsense), check the settings. If you're profiling with your actual ipad, you should set the setting to "Release". This worked for me in the past.

Comment: In my case i have valid certificates, as i have been using them to export app to app store. when i try to profile using release certificate on profile , it throws error of "App installation failed A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found." and when try to profile on debug mode is crashes on right after app lunch. its totally hopeless :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im sure there can be other causes but I had this one myself.

What happened was I updated one of my framework path locations but I didn't update my build settings.

What this meant was my code was compiling and working when I would 'run it normally' but when I ran in instruments it just crashed.

The problem is, the app should have been crashing when I ran it normally. When I cleaned my project, the app stopped working and showed me the error message I needed (my framework wasn't installed correctly).

So to anyone who encounters this its worth cleaning your project and then running it. It may crash and give you the problem at hand so you can fix it.

Comment: This answer helped me. Be sure to also Build for Profiling. Running an instrument on "Debug" or "Running" crashes iOS on my end.